# Developer console not working

Tags: apex, visualforce, developer-console

I am not able to use **salesforce developer console**, I have admin privilege in my org.

When I try to use the developer console using **any browser** I am getting below frozen screen.

I tried reopening, but nothing is working.

[image: Developer console]

Comment: Tried incognito also but not working.

Comment: How long do you wait, and have you tried looking at the browser's inspector to see what's going on?

Comment: I tired waiting for up to 20 mins.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: b is not a function
    at h.loadContent (ApexIDEPanels_Ext4.js:344)
    at h.<anonymous> (ApexIDEPanels_Ext4.js:185)
    at h.fire (ext-all.js:18)
    at h.continueFireEvent (ext-all.js:18)
    at h.fireEvent (ext-all.js:18)
    at h.fireEvent (ext-all.js:18)
    at h.f (ApexIDEPanels_Ext4.js:188)
    at h.fire (ext-all.js:18)
    at h.continueFireEvent (ext-all.js:18)
    at h.fireEvent (ext-all.js:18)

Comment: OK, you may have to raise a support case to ask Salesforce to clear history out of your user's usage of the console. Do you know if other admins on the same org have the same problem?

Comment: I tried to inspect, one of the exception message in browser console is pasted above.

Comment: I checked with other developer in the org who is having admin privilege. They are not facing this issue.

Comment: I think it's time to raise it with Salesforce as a Support Case, if you can.

Comment: Sure, I will do that.

Comment: @PhilW There's a fix in Help, actually.

Comment: @sfdcfox, Cool. I hadn't found that. That's why I use this forum - always something new to learn!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to contact support. You can fix this yourself.

This is noted in the Help topic "[Developer Console menus are unresponsive](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000332898&type=1&mode=1)'

> 1. Login to Workbench and go to REST Explorer

> 2. Use the following query in Workbench to get the IDEWorkspace

> /services/data/v31.0/tooling/query/?q=SELECT id, name from IDEWorkspace

> ID of IDEWorkspace is "1dexxxxxxxxxxxxxx".

> 3. Do GET operation for the found id with following query "/services/data/v29.0/tooling/sobjects/IDEWorkspace/1de1a0000014sEWAAY"

> 4. You will see the content of IDEWorkspace

> 5. Do DELETE operation on found record.

> 6. Re-open Developer Console.

> 7. Developer Console will work fine. As we created a new workspace and the old workspace has been deleted.And the slowness will also be removed.

Comment: Thank you so much @sfdcfox, It worked.